# Rewriting URLs using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to re-write the URL of one file.  I want thankyou.php to show up as /thank-you/. I have gotten this to work only partially.

I have this one rule in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^thank-you/?$    thankyou.php    [NC,L]
```

I can get this to work for domain.com/thank-you but NOT for domain.com/thank-you/

For some reason the last slash is not working.

Can anyone help me out with this..??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What doesn't "work" exactly? Are you getting a 404? Or are all your relative links broken?

Comment: Hi. Yes, the relative links are broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes, the relative links are broken.

Your relative links are broken because the browser sees the URL `http://example.com/thank-you/`, so all relative links will resolve to the base `/thank-you/` (e.g. `/thank-you/styles/mystyle.css`).

Change all your links to absolute URLs or add a relative URI base to the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: Ok, thanx. But is this the only way..??  Is there no way to accomplish this using rules in my htaccess file..??  Seems like this would be a common problem folks would need to solve.

Comment: @user3512522 this is a far better way than routing each and every request in an attempt to try to find the correct base of bad relative URLs

Comment: Thanx.  I will use the base-href method of solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Question mark at the end of your rule says, that this last character is optional. Did you try to use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^thank-you\/$ thankyou.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi. Tried your suggestion and the one that was working ceased to work..!!  domain.com/thank-you stopped working.